# PyQuery get text node

Tags: python, pyquery

I'm using PyQuery to process this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <strong>Personality: Strengths</strong>
    <br />
    Text
    <br />
    <br />
    <strong>Personality: Weaknesses</strong>
    <br />
    Text
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

Now that I've got a variable `e` point to `.container`, I'm looping through its children:

```
for c in e.iterchildren():
    print c.tag
```

but in this way I can't get text nodes (the two `Text` string)

How can I loop an element's children include text nodes?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it likes

```
        for c in e.children():
            p = PyQuery(c)
            print p.__str__()  
            #here re.sub remove html tag
```

This code could get the raw text of each node.
If you want to distinguish the text tag from others :

```
            raw = p.__str__().strip()
            a = raw.rfind(">")
            if (a+1!=len(raw)) : 
                print 'is text'
```